# Http Request without Cookies and Session-Data

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I am currently having a problem I tried to solve the whole afternoon:

I would like to make a http.get-Request to a URL on the same domain without sending Cookies and Session-Data (The user should see a preview of his page without beeing logged in), but as I am new to JS and, in particular, to Angular2  I have my problems...

At the moment my request looks like this:

```
private preview(url):Promise<any> {
    http.get(url, {withCredentials: false})
    .toPromise()
    .etc ...
```

But I don't think withCredentials applies to this situation...

Any advice is much appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: where you able to solve this problem?

Comment: do you have any solution on this yet?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I came across similar situation. I need to remove JSessionId from a particular request.